# Mute embedded Vine whenever it's not in the viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, vine

So I know how to mute audio when the embedded Vine loads, but I want it to mute again when the user scrolls away. Is there any way to accomplish this using iframe?

Here's a random example Vine:

```
<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/ixH9YPXVXBv/embed/simple?audio=1" width="600" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe><script src="https://platform.vine.co/static/scripts/embed.js"></script>
```